# What is the minimum Passport validity when applying for Niederlassungsurlaubnis?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, passport, blue-card

If all the criteria are met for the German PR, what is the minimum Passport validity should I have in my Passport when applying? I was told from someone it is at least 6 months but I have not found any solid information online.